# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php

Error:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\wamp\www\cdij\editquantity.php on line 8

Here is the Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$quantity=$_POST['txt_quantity'];
$name=$_POST['Fields'];
$table=$_POST['editwhat'];

$que="UPDATE `material` SET `material_quantity`='".$quantity."' WHERE `material_name`='".$name."'";
mysql_query($con,$que);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: You need to check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and you'd find your answer (which is that your $con and $que are the wrong way around. Whenever you get an error like this, you should always check the PHP pages for that function to see if you've used it correctly.

Comment: While you're reading the documentation, take note that you should be transitioning off from `mysql_*` functions completely, as they are on the way to deprecation. Use PDO or `mysqli_` instead. **Your code is highly susceptible to SQL injection attack.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the $con and $que paramters in your mysql_query function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I did That, But now value is not getting updated into that table, material_quantity column's Data Type is integer

Comment: That's a different question, and perhaps one where you need to look at the quality of the variables going in to your code. For debugging you should always make your first step to use "echo $que" to show yourself what your query string looks like, and compare it to your database

Comment: UPDATE `material` SET `material_quantity`='102' WHERE `material_name`='Hoses1'..getting this as the output. with the same code i posted above. But won't update into database.

Answer (score 4):

The right syntax for `mysql_query` is the opposite of your. From documentation

```
mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

So you need to change to

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Since connection link is not required if you only use a database connection you migh not use it

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

You might need to select your database after connection

```
bool mysql_select_db ( string $database_name [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

As side note i would advise you to switch to either [**`PDO`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**`mysqli`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) since [`mysql_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) api are deprecated and soon will be no longer mantained

Answer (score 2):

STOP USING mysql_ METHODS THEY ARE DEPRECATED AND VERY UNSAFE.

Instead use mysqli_, you should learn how to use this rather than trying to continue to learn mysql_ methods.

See Here:
https://www.php.net/mysqli

Answer (score 1):

You are using **mysqli_query** syntax but using **mysql_query**!
Well the best part of the mistake is, you need to upgrade to **mysqli_query** and you are already half way around, which is really great.

mysql_query is depricated. Check this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), and you are there. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

problem in parameter sequeance in **mysql_query()**.

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bkd_rev');
$sql = 'select * from tbl';                       
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

if you want to pass connection object then,

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Answer (score 0):

the first parameter should be the query it suppose t

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
```